# Making bread fast and with few ingredients

Tags: bread, quickbread

so I'm writing a story where one of the characters is trying to make some bread with minimal ingredients in a short amount of time. I'm not having much luck with my normal means of researching so I came here for some help. I'd like to know what bread takes the shortest amount of time. Breads that can be made with minimal ingredients. And also I would just like to know if you have to knead flat bread.

Comment: What are you thinking of when you say "bread"?  Something risen and baked?  If your definition is loose enough, you can make a tortilla with two ingredients (flour and water) in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Perhaps suited for https://writing.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Would it be better if this question was narrowed to just whether flatbreads are kneaded?

Comment: @ReputableMisnomer: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com was my thought: it's for questions about getting details of things (usually science or history) to fit what a story needs.  Sometimes such questions can be on-topic on physics or chemistry.SE, or in this case cooking.SE.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the title to also include the time constraint. Sprouted grain bread (Essene bread or Ezekiel bread) can be made with a single ingredient - sprouts of a single grain - but to make it from scratch will take a couple of days.

Comment: Years ago I did a camel safari in Rajasthan and the guide was very adept at making chapati when we stopped for meals. He'd ask a couple of people to gather wood, make a fire, mix up flour and water, put a bit of mix on the metal plate - and in a minute or so there was a chapati.

Comment: Ask a Jewish friend why we eat matzah on Passover. (Flour, water, "no time to rise.")

Comment: As much as I am wanting to help, asking for recipe recommendations is off topic here. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 22):

A basic *flatbread* can be made by mixing flour, a little oil (if possible) and just enough water to make it stick together. Salt is often added.  No real kneading is needed, just mixing, but a little kneading helps.  Then roll/pound/press flat and cook in a frying pan or on a hot stone. In Egypt I've seen something similar cooked on the side of an old jerrycan over a wood fire.  This is basically what a [chapati](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/233531/quick-whole-wheat-chapati/) is, so very recognisably bread (but not risen).

Comment: I don't know why, but this question recalls to me the story of [Elijah and the Widow at Zarephath](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Kings+17%3A7-16&version=NIV) which I can't have read in nearly 30 years

Answer (score 16):

Your two requirements are somewhat at cross-purpose. The minimal ingredients for a fairly typical bread are flour and water, but then you need to have several days to weeks to establish a working starter.

If you are willing to have a three-ingredients bread, then your best choice is a soda bread. You only need flour, water and baking powder. The time would be about 5 minutes for mixing it and 25 minutes for baking (can be more depending on the shape of your mold). A yeast bread can also be made with three ingredients - water, flour and yeast - but it needs a couple of hours for kneading and rising before it can be baked. Flatbreads like pita or lavash will also need this time for kneading and rising.

As somebody mentioned in a comment, if you are willing to relax your definition of "bread", you can have a tortilla or maybe something cracker-like prepared in a very short time, and without the need for an oven, with only flour and water.

Comment: The soda bread can be backed on a [stick over open fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_bread), so I'd go for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

A cup of oats mixed with 2 cups of natural yoghurt will make a "bread" loaf in a lined tin.
Paul

Comment: Then you bake this? for how long? Does it have to sit, be kneaded, etc? Can you [edit] to include more details?